# display a linear highchart with data from database

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, highcharts

i'm trying to display data from database into a `linear highchart`. this is the `json` response from my controller which is retrieved from database:

```
[{"protocole":"tcp","date":"01/02/20","time":"00:10:20","total":281},
{"protocole":"udp","date":"01/02/20","time":"00:10:30","total":201},
{"protocole":"tcp","date":"01/02/20","time":"00:10:40","total":100}}
```

i succeeded to display data in the `yAxix` from data base but i've tested it with static data in the `xAxix` this is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options={
         chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },
        title : {
          text: 'Total Request number'   
       },
       subtitle : {
          text: 'Server num1'
       },
        xAxis : {
          categories: ['00:10:20','00:10:30','00:10:40']
       },
        yAxis :{
          title: {
             text: 'Total'
          },
          plotLines: [{
             value: 0,
             width: 1,
             color: '#808080'
          }]
       },   

        tooltip : {
          valueSuffix: '\xB0C'
       },

        legend : {
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'right',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          borderWidth: 0
       },

        series : [{}]

    }
 $.ajax({
type: 'GET',
contentType : 'application/json',
dataType: 'JSON',
url: 'jsonsdp',
data: "",
success: function(data){
     var array=[] ;
    $.each(data, function(i) {


        array.push(data[i].total); 

        })
         alert(array);
    options.series[0]= {"name": 'total',
            "data":array};


    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

}
});

});
```

now i want the `categories` to be dynamic and retrieve `time` and put it on axis .
I have tried this code  but still not working !

```
  $.ajax({
type: 'GET',
contentType : 'application/json',
dataType: 'JSON',
url: 'jsonsdp',
data: "",
success: function(data){
     var array=[] ;
   var array1=[];
    $.each(data, function(i) {


        array.push(data[i].total); 
      array1.push(data[i].time);
        })
        // alert(array);
    options.series[0]= {"name": 'total',
            "data":array};
        options.xAxis.categories=array1;

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

}
});
```

do somebody have an idea how to do this ?
thanks in advance .

Comment: have you checked the console? is there any error? also just before you set the categories, have you tried checking what are the contents of array1?

Comment: i've tested array1 with an alert..yes it contains the time array from database

Comment: the console contains an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` do you know what does this mean ?

Comment: it shows you a lines number as well, if you click on it, it will take you to the line which causes this error. If you could point out which line this is and edit the question to add this?

Comment: i've changed `options.xAxis.categories=array1;` to `options.xAxis.categories={"data:array1}; `it's gone.
the chart is shown but the xAxis is set to '0,1,2'   and not the values of array1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this code and it works perfectly ! 
I don't know why this didn't work for the first time  and showed errors and now works !
I post it maybe it could help someOne. if someone knows why it will be better to mention it .

```
 $.ajax({
type: 'GET',
contentType : 'application/json',
dataType: 'JSON',
url: 'jsonsdp',
data: "",
success: function(data){
 var array=[] ;
var array1=[];
$.each(data, function(i) {


    array.push(data[i].total); 
  array1.push(data[i].time);
    })
    // alert(array);
options.series[0]= {"name": 'total',
        "data":array};
    options.xAxis.categories=array1;

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

}
});
```